# UNPIVOT Holiday Hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table, that keeps track of store holiday hours:

```
LOCATION_ID DATE1       TIMES1          DATE2       TIMES2
123456      2020-12-12  10:00AM-09:00PM 2020-12-19  10:00AM-09:00PM
```

This is a highly oversimplified table. There's about 30 columns horzontially consisting of store operating hours by date - It continues (DATE3, TIMES3, DATE4, TIMES4, etc).

I need to unpivot the values vertically, ensuring the date and time values are on the same record.

(NOTE: Once I figure out to structure the `UNPIVOT` expression properly, I will use Dynamic SQL on my own to pivot the column names)

Desired Outcome:

```
LOCATION_ID    DATE         TIME
123456         2020-12-12   10:00AM-09:00PM
123456         2020-12-19   10:00AM-09:00PM
```

I tried using `UNPIVOT`, but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #HOURS (LOCATION_ID int, DATE1 varchar(255), TIMES1 varchar(255), DATE2 
varchar(255), TIMES2 varchar(255));

INSERT INTO #HOURS VALUES ('123456', '2020-12-12', '10:00AM-09:00PM','2020-12-19','10:00AM-09:00PM' )
```

Code that I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT location_id, 
               [date1], 
               [times1], 
               [date2] 
        FROM   #hours) AS cp 
       UNPIVOT ( pivotvalues 
               FOR pivvalues IN ([Date1], 
                                 [date2], 
                                 [times1]) ) AS up1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon is 100% correct (+1).

However, if you are looking for a dynamic approach WITHOUT having to use Dynamic SQL, consider the following.

**Example**

```
Select Location_ID
      ,Date  = max(case when [Item] like 'DATE%' then Value end)
      ,Time  = max(case when [Item] like 'TIME%' then Value end)
 From (
        select A.Location_ID
              ,Grp = replace(replace([Item],'DATE',''),'TIMES','')
              ,B.*
         from #hours  A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-XML-Unpivot-Row]( (Select A.* for XML RAW) ) B
         Where [Item] not in ('LOCATION_ID')
      ) A
 Group By Location_ID,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Location_ID   Date          Time
123456        2020-12-12    10:00AM-09:00PM
123456        2020-12-19    10:00AM-09:00PM
```

**The Table-Valued Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
         From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
)
```

Comment: Thanks John! I'm getting a Syntax error - Is that because we're on SQL server 2012?

Comment: @DepthofField Updated for an XML version vs. the JSON approach.

Comment: Hmmm, not recognizing tvf-XML-Unpivot-Row

Invalid object name 'dbo.tvf-XML-Unpivot-Row

Comment: @DepthofField apply the CREATE FUNCTION  first

Comment: GENIUS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DepthofField My wife would dispute that.  :)  Always happy to help

Comment: Oh, I had immediately accepted the other one, since it was the first answer posted ! In hindsight, Yours does work better for me, since it handles columns dynamically, and was Updated to work with 2012. Updated as such :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . Your versions using XML and JSON are always very clever.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `unpivot`.  Use `apply`:

```
select h.location_id, v.date, v.time
from #hours h cross apply
     (values (h.date1, h.times1), (h.date2, h.times2)
     ) v(date, time);
```

`unpivot` is non-standard syntax that does exactly one thing.  `APPLY` is the SQL Server implementation of *lateral join*s.  This is a very powerful `join` type -- using it for unpivoting is a good way to start learning the syntax.